# collect2.exe Id returned 1 exit status (Dev-c++)

Tags: c++

I am using Dev-c++ 5.11 and the compiler is ""TDM-GCC 4.92 64-Bit Release"".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

I got errors

```
        C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/crt2.o:(.text+0x2ec): undefined reference to `__imp____set_app_type'
    C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/crt2.o:(.text+0x30c): undefined reference to `__imp____set_app_type'
    C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/crt2.o:(.text+0x322): undefined reference to `__imp__atexit'
    C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/crt2.o:(.text+0x332): undefined reference to `__imp___onexit'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status D:\대회\Makefile.win:25: recipe for target 'Project2.exe' failed
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [Project2.exe] Error 1
```

Makefile.win is below

```
    # Project: Project2
    # Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.11

    CPP      = g++.exe
    CC       = gcc.exe
    WINDRES  = windres.exe
    OBJ      = main.o
    LINKOBJ  = main.o
    LIBS     = -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc
    INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include"
    CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++"
    BIN      = Project2.exe
    CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) 
    CFLAGS   = $(INCS) 
    RM       = rm.exe -f

    .PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

    all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

    clean: clean-custom
       ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

    $(BIN): $(OBJ)
       $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

    main.o: main.cpp
       $(CPP) -c main.cpp -o main.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

and it is highlighted in line 25.

which is

```
   $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
```

I googled a lot but still I couldn't solve it.

I want a success compile.

Comment: The error and output you show is not the complete output. Please edit your question to include the copy-pasted (as text) full and complete output. And it's important that you copy-paste the actual text, and not rewrite what you think it says, as if you rewrite you might add errors by mistake, like your misspelling of `ld` as `Id`.

Comment: I edited it. I wanted to paste the whole output, but it sad I need more detail. what i add is the last part and the rest is all 'undefined reference'